# What is the reason for this code conversion failure?

Tags: c#, vb.net, telerik, code-conversion, vb.net-to-c#

I'm using [the telerik code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) to try to convert this VB code to C#:

```
''' <summary>
''' Return the name of a property, field, or local variable from a lambda expression.
''' </summary>
''' <typeparam name="T">Type of the property, field, or local variable.</typeparam>
''' <param name="expr">A lambda expression that refers to a property, field, or local variable, in the
''' form: '() => Class.Property' or '() => object.Property'.</param>
''' <returns>The name of the property represented by the provided lambda expression.</returns>
Friend Function GetMemberName(Of T)(expr As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T))) As String
    Dim memberExpr As System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression = TryCast(expr.Body, System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression)

    If memberExpr Is Nothing Then _
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The argument must be a lambda expression in the form: " &
        "'() => Class.Member', '() => object.Member', or '() => fieldOrLocal'")

    Const VBLocalPrefix = "$VB$Local_" 'odd prefix in $VB$ for local variable member names.
    GetMemberName = memberExpr.Member.Name
    If (GetMemberName.StartsWith(VBLocalPrefix)) Then GetMemberName = GetMemberName.Substring(VBLocalPrefix.Length)
End Function
```

I'm getting this error message in the output pane:

> CONVERSION ERROR: Code could not be converted. Details:
>
> -- line 8 col 8: invalid NonModuleDeclaration
>
> Please check for any errors in the original code and try again.

I've [Googled telerik "invalid NonModuleDeclaration"](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=telerik+%22invalid+NonModuleDeclaration%22) and ["invalid NonModuleDeclaration"](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=%22invalid+NonModuleDeclaration%22) and perused the results, but they all essentially give work-arounds (i.e. the answering party says "here is the conversion I did manually for you) and don't explain what is causing the failure or how to avoid it.

I know I can figure out how to manually convert the code, but my question is: why is the converter failing to convert this code?

Comment: I get the error at line 8, column 8 - which is, if I'm not mistaken, this part: `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T))`.

Comment: My bad, I had removed the XML docs to try to see if that was the reason and also the code had indents -- and I copied the output from that.  I get the same line/col when I put it back (updated).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem! It is due to this line:

```vb
Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The argument must be a lambda expression in the form: " &
    "'() => Class.Member', '() => object.Member', or '() => fieldOrLocal'")
```

Maybe the converter isn't up to date, but adding an underscore after the ampersand fixes the problem and the code is now converted successfully:

```vb
Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The argument must be a lambda expression in the form: " & _
    "'() => Class.Member', '() => object.Member', or '() => fieldOrLocal'")
```

Comment: @roryap : No problem! Glad I could help.